# Como configurar un tipo de mapa de terrenos (bienes raices) que sea dinámico, ¿ que opciones tengo?

Tags: nodejs, backend

resulta que me encuentro desarrollando un sistema para la gestión de propiedades sin embargo yo no soy el que programa pero si el PO. Para poner un ejemplo, imaginemos que tengo un plano de AutoCAD de planta de estacionamientos, quiero que de alguna forma este plano me muestre de distintos colores que estacionamientos están disponibles o bloqueados, si selecciono un estacionamiento poder realizar una cotización o ver mas información sobre este, esto aplica también para terrenos de propiedades. Si alguno tiene una idea o le gustaría profundizar, agradecido que me contacte o escriba.
Adjunto ejemplo.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Hola amigo, Bienvenido al Sitio, He verificado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask], Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], He visto que has agregado Imágenes, es preferible que tus ejemplos sean en texto y facilites el uso del mismo, También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: disculpa que lenguaje de programación estas usando y que código?

Comment: El lenguaje es Javascript, el framework Nodejs